# User Upload Quota Fortigate - 501E (6.2.1)

Tags: firewall, fortigate, fortinet

Im using a Fortigate 501E. 
my requirement is: Every user can’t upload more than 1 GB per day.
is it possible to implement the above requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTTP, you can use the Web Filter for per-IP user quotas. Set the required categories to Monitor, Warning, or Authenticate and create a Category Usage Quota with type Traffic.

You'll likely need to create an additional policy for that Web Filter and put it in front, or the quota will be counted across all monitored categories.

I don't think it's possible to count uploads specifically, but you could deny HTTP post on the normal policy to force a move to the quota policy.